# How to extract the results of Http Requests in Elm

Tags: json, http, io, elm

Using Elm's [html](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/elm-html/4.0.2/Html) package it is possible to make http requests:

```
https://api.github.com/users/nytimes/repos
```

These are all the [New York Times](https://api.github.com/users/nytimes/repos) repos on Github.  Basically there are two items I'd want from the Github response, the **id** and **name**

```
[ { "id": 5803599,  "name": "backbone.stickit"  , ... }, 
  { "id": 21172032, "name": "collectd-rabbitmq" , ... }, 
  { "id": 698445,   "name": "document-viewer"   , ... }, ... ]
```

The Elm type for `Http.get` requires a Json [`Decoder`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/1.0.0/Json-Decode) object

```
> Http.get
<function> : Json.Decode.Decoder a -> String -> Task.Task Http.Error a
```

I don't know how to open lists yet.  So I put the decoder `Json.Decode.string` and at least the types matched, but I had no idea what to do with the [`task`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/2.1.0/Task) object.

```
> tsk = Http.get (Json.Decode.list Json.Decode.string) url
{ tag = "AndThen", task = { tag = "Catch", task = { tag = "Async", asyncFunction = <function> }, callback = <function> }, callback = <function> }
    : Task.Task Http.Error (List String)

> Task.toResult tsk
{ tag = "Catch", task = { tag = "AndThen", task = { tag = "AndThen", task = { tag = "Catch", task = { tag = "Async", asyncFunction = <function> }, callback = <function> }, callback = <function> }, callback = <function> }, callback = <function> }
    : Task.Task a (Result.Result Http.Error (List String))
```

I just want an Elm object of the repo names so I can display in some `div` elements, but I can't even get the data out.

---

Can someone **slowly** walk me through how to write the decoder and how to get the data out with Elm?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Update for Elm 0.17:**

I have updated the complete gist of this answer to work with Elm 0.17. You can [see the full source code here](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/7f86ed7683cfeeec4557). It will run on http://elm-lang.org/try.

A number of language and API changes were made in 0.17 that make some of the following recommendations obsolete. You can [read about the 0.17 upgrade plan here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-platform/blob/master/upgrade-docs/0.17.md).

I will leave the original answer for 0.16 untouched below, but you can [compare the final gists to see a list of what has changed](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/7f86ed7683cfeeec4557/revisions). I believe the newer 0.17 version is cleaner and easier to understand.

**Original Answer for Elm 0.16:**

It looks like you're using the Elm REPL. [As noted here](https://github.com/elm-lang/elm-repl/issues/72#issuecomment-127368114), you're not going to be able to execute tasks in the REPL. We'll get to more on *why* in a bit. Instead, let's create an actual Elm project.

I'm assuming you've downloaded the standard [Elm tools](http://elm-lang.org/install).

You'll first need to create a project folder and open it up in a terminal.

A common way to get started on an Elm project is to use the [StartApp](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/evancz/start-app/latest/StartApp). Let's use that as a starting point. You first need to use the Elm package manager command line tool to install the required packages. Run the following in a terminal in your project root:

```bsh
elm package install -y evancz/elm-html
elm package install -y evancz/elm-effects
elm package install -y evancz/elm-http
elm package install -y evancz/start-app
```

Now, create a file at the project root called Main.elm. Here is some boilerplate StartApp code to get you started. I won't go into explaining the details here since this question is specifically about Tasks. You can learn more by going through the [Elm Architecture Tutorial](https://github.com/evancz/elm-architecture-tutorial). For now, copy this into Main.elm.

```elm
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Http
import StartApp
import Task exposing (Task)
import Effects exposing (Effects, Never)
import Json.Decode as Json exposing ((:=))

type Action
  = NoOp

type alias Model =
  { message : String }

app = StartApp.start
  { init = init
  , update = update
  , view = view
  , inputs = [ ]
  }

main = app.html

port tasks : Signal (Task.Task Effects.Never ())
port tasks = app.tasks

init =
  ({ message = "Hello, Elm!" }, Effects.none)

update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Effects.none)

view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  div []
    [ div [] [ text model.message ]
    ]
```

You can now run this code using elm-reactor. Go to the terminal in your project folder and enter

```bsh
elm reactor
```

This will run a web server on port 8000 by default, and you can pull up http://localhost:8000 in your browser, then navigate to Main.elm to see the "Hello, Elm" example.

The end goal here is to create a button which, when clicked, pulls in the list of nytimes repositories and lists the IDs and names of each. Let's first create that button. We'll do so by using the standard html generation functions. Update the `view` function with something like this:

```elm
view address model =
  div []
    [ div [] [ text model.message ]
    , button [] [ text "Click to load nytimes repositories" ]
    ]
```

On its own, the button click does nothing. We need to create an Action that is then handled by the `update` function. The action the button is initiating is to fetch data from the Github endpoint. `Action` now becomes:

```elm
type Action
  = NoOp
  | FetchData
```

And we can now stub out the handling of this action in the `update` function like so. For now, let's change the message to show that the button click was handled:

```elm
update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Effects.none)
    FetchData ->
      ({ model | message = "Initiating data fetch!" }, Effects.none)
```

Lastly, we have to cause button clicks to trigger that new action. This is done using the `onClick` function, which generates a click event handler for that button. The button html generation line now looks like this:

```elm
button [ onClick address FetchData ] [ text "Click to load nytimes repositories" ]
```

Great! Now the message should be updated when you click it. Let's move onto Tasks.

As I mentioned earlier, the REPL does not (yet) support the invoking of tasks. This may seem counterintuitive if you're coming from an imperative language like Javascript, where when you write code that says "go fetch data from this url," it immediately creates an HTTP request. In a purely functional language like Elm, you do things a little differently. When you create a Task in Elm, you're really just indicating your intentions, creating a sort of "package" that you can hand off to the runtime in order to do something that causes side effects; in this case, contact the outside world and pull data down from a URL.

Let's go ahead and create a task that fetches the data from the url. First, we're going to need a type inside Elm to represent the shape of the data we care about. You indicated that you just wanted the `id` and `name` fields.

```elm
type alias RepoInfo =
  { id : Int
  , name : String
  }
```

As a note about type construction inside Elm, let's stop for a minute and talk about how we create RepoInfo instances. Since there are two fields, you can construct a `RepoInfo` in one of two ways. The following two statements are equivalent:

```elm
-- This creates a record using record syntax construction
{ id = 123, name = "example" }

-- This creates an equivalent record using RepoInfo as a constructor with two args
RepoInfo 123 "example"
```

That second was of constructing the instance will become more important when we talk about Json decoding.

Let's also add a list of these to the model. We'll have to change the `init` function as well to start off with an empty list.

```elm
type alias Model =
  { message : String
  , repos : List RepoInfo
  }

init =
  let
    model =
      { message = "Hello, Elm!"
      , repos = []
      }
  in
    (model, Effects.none)
```

Since the data from the URL comes back in JSON format, We'll need a Json Decoder to translate the raw JSON into our type-safe Elm class. Create the following decoder.

```elm
repoInfoDecoder : Json.Decoder RepoInfo
repoInfoDecoder =
  Json.object2
    RepoInfo
    ("id" := Json.int) 
    ("name" := Json.string)
```

Let's pick that apart. A decoder is what maps the raw JSON to the shape of the type to which we're mapping. In this case, our type is a simple record alias with two fields. Remember that I mentioned a few steps ago that we can create a RepoInfo instance by using `RepoInfo` as a function that takes two parameters? That's why we're using `Json.object2` to create the decoder. The first arg to `object` is a function that takes two arguments itself, and that's why we're passing in `RepoInfo`. It is equivalent to a function with arity two.

The remaining arguments spell out the shape of the type. Since our `RepoInfo` model lists `id` first and `name` second, that's the order in which the decoder expects the arguments to be.

We'll need another decoder to decode a list of `RepoInfo` instances.

```elm
repoInfoListDecoder : Json.Decoder (List RepoInfo)
repoInfoListDecoder =
  Json.list repoInfoDecoder
```

Now that we have a model and decoder, we can create a function that returns the task for fetching the data. Remember, this isn't actually fetching any data, it's merely creating a function which we can hand off to the runtime later.

```elm
fetchData : Task Http.Error (List RepoInfo)
fetchData =
  Http.get repoInfoListDecoder "https://api.github.com/users/nytimes/repos"
```

There are a number of ways of handling the variety of errors that can occur. Let's choose [Task.toResult](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Task#toResult), which maps the result of the request to a [Result](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-lang/core/3.0.0/Result#Result) type. It will make things easier on us in a bit, and is sufficient for this example. Let's change that `fetchData` signature to this:

```elm
fetchData : Task x (Result Http.Error (List RepoInfo))
fetchData =
  Http.get repoInfoListDecoder "https://api.github.com/users/nytimes/repos"
    |> Task.toResult
```

Note that I'm using `x` in my type annotation for the error value of Task. That's just because, by mapping to a `Result`, I'll never have to care about an error from the task.

Now, we're going to need some actions to handle the two possible results: An HTTP error or a successful result. Update `Action` with this:

```elm
type Action
  = NoOp
  | FetchData
  | ErrorOccurred String
  | DataFetched (List RepoInfo)
```

Your update function should now set those values on the model.

```elm
update action model =
  case action of
    NoOp ->
      (model, Effects.none)
    FetchData ->
      ({ model | message = "Initiating data fetch!" }, Effects.none)
    ErrorOccurred errorMessage ->
      ({ model | message = "Oops! An error occurred: " ++ errorMessage }, Effects.none)
    DataFetched repos ->
      ({ model | repos = repos, message = "The data has been fetched!" }, Effects.none)
```

Now, we need a way to map the `Result` task to one of these new actions. Since I don't want to get bogged down in error handling, I'm just going to use `toString` to change the error object into a string for debugging purposes

```elm
httpResultToAction : Result Http.Error (List RepoInfo) -> Action
httpResultToAction result =
  case result of
    Ok repos ->
      DataFetched repos
    Err err ->
      ErrorOccurred (toString err)
```

That gives us a way to map a never-failing task to an Action. However, StartApp deals with Effects, which is a thin layer over Tasks (as well as a few other things). We'll need one more piece before we can tie it all together, and that's a way to map the never-failing HTTP task to an Effects of our type Action.

```elm
fetchDataAsEffects : Effects Action
fetchDataAsEffects =
  fetchData
    |> Task.map httpResultToAction
    |> Effects.task
```

You may have noticed I called this thing, "never failing." That was confusing to me at first so let me try to explain. When we create a task, we're guaranteed a result, but it a success or failure. In order to make Elm apps as robust as possible, we in essence remove the possibility of failure (by which I mainly mean, an unhandled Javascript exception), by explicitly handling every case. That's why we've gone through the trouble of mapping first to a `Result` and then to our `Action`, which explicitly handles error messages. To say it never fails is not to say that HTTP problems can't happen, it's to say that we're handling every possible outcome, and errors are mapped to "successes" by mapping them to a valid action.

Before our final step, let's make sure our `view` can show the list of repositories.

```elm
view : Signal.Address Action -> Model -> Html
view address model =
  let
    showRepo repo =
      li []
        [ text ("Repository ID: " ++ (toString repo.id) ++ "; ")
        , text ("Repository Name: " ++ repo.name)
        ]
  in
    div []
      [ div [] [ text model.message ]
      , button [ onClick address FetchData ] [ text "Click to load nytimes repositories" ]
      , ul [] (List.map showRepo model.repos)
      ]
```

Lastly, the piece that ties this all together is to make the `FetchData` case of our `update` function return the Effect which initiates our task. Update the case statement like this:

```elm
FetchData ->
  ({ model | message = "Initiating data fetch!" }, fetchDataAsEffects)
```

That's it! You can now run `elm reactor` and click the button to fetch the list of repositories. If you want to test out the error handling, you can just mangle the URL for the `Http.get` request to see what happens.

I've posted the entire working example of this [as a gist](https://gist.github.com/freakingawesome/7f86ed7683cfeeec4557). If you don't want to run it locally, you can see the final result by pasting that code into http://elm-lang.org/try.

I've tried to be very explicit and concise about each step along the way. In a typical Elm app, a lot of these steps will be condensed down to a few lines, and more idiomatic shorthand will be used. I've tried to spare you those hurdles by making things as small and explicit as possible. I hope this helps!

Comment: This is the kind of answer that makes me push forward to learn Elm. Ok, it's hard to grasp at first and can twist your brain, 0.16 -> 0.17 update is painful... but looks like the community is really, really kind and open to new comers. Thank you very much for the time you spent writing this answer, helped me a lot.